# Where is underlying data for IDENT_CURRENT stored?

Tags: sql-server

Ok.. a silly litte question.  Honestly, it's not important for what I'm doing, but I've just gotta know!

I created a table with an IDENTITY(1,1) column.  I insert no rows.  I used

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(table, RESEED, 10000)
```

I run the following:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table')
SELECT last_value, seed_value
FROM sys.identity_columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('table');
```

The first returns 10000.  The second returns NULL, 1 (the original seed value).

Where is 10000 stored?

Comment: [sys.identity_columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-identity-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a view, not a table. The identity value is a property of the table itself

Comment: sys.tables doesn't seem to have an applicable column.  Can you provide SQL that gives the answer?

Comment: Did you look at the column "seed_value"? If last_value is null then use seed_value

Comment: Checked it.  As I posted, the second query returns 1 for seed_value.

Comment: I get what you are asking but using IDENT_CURRENT is not reliable. https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current I don't know where to find the reseed value....interesting question.

Comment: Thanks. I’m aware of that link and wasn’t using it in that way. This is more of a curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not documented and is subject to change but it is stored in the left most X bytes of `idtval` in `sys.syscolpars`.

The value of `X` depends on the datatype of the underlying column. For an `int` it is 4.

Immediately after running

```
CREATE TABLE [table1](Foo int IDENTITY)
```

The following query (only can be executed using the DAC) ...

```
SELECT *,
       CAST(CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(idtval, 4)) AS BINARY(4)) AS INT)
FROM   sys.syscolpars
WHERE  id = OBJECT_ID('table1')
```

... Returns

[image]

After running

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT([table1], RESEED, 10000)
```

It returns

[image]

Comment: That is so cool!  (I'm ashamed to admit that I didn't even know about the DAC.)